# how to clear old data when calling again same function in javascript using firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase

[image]I'm trying to clear old data and load the new data from firebase database on button click, on the same div. But when, first i load data and it is working fine but when i'm trying to fetch or load new data in replace of new one it show the data just below to the old data...

This is My JS code:-

```
function getusersdata(ca)
{



        var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("users").orderByChild('designation').equalTo(ca);

    rootRef.on("child_added", snap =>{

        var name = snap.child("name").val();
        var designation = snap.child("designation").val();

        $("#ServicesData").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + designation + "</td></tr>");



    });




}
```

This is HTML code:-

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="border: 0px; border-radius: 2px;" onclick="getusersdata('CA')" id="CA">CA</button>
```

CS

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer lies in the way you are scoping your variables.

[Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

If you want the variables in question to die with the function, they will need to be declared as local variables to that function.  An undeclared variable is automatically made global in JavaScript.  A global variable will then remain persistent across function calls.

If making a local declaration is not an option for some reason (or if this really does need to be a global variable) you will want to look to resetting the required variables somewhere between subsequent function calls for that function.

(Generally speaking, all variables should be declared at the start of their respective scopes.  There are exceptions, but this is generally a good aim.)

Comment: Did you look at the page on scope?  If you want a variable to reset or stop to exist when the function containing it ends, it must be a local variable.  Otherwise you will have to reset that variable for re-use from an empty state if the function is called again.

Answer (score 0):

The problems lays with `$("#ServicesData").append()`

You append (add) the new results to the existing DOM table. You have to first remove the `<tr>`from the old dataset and then append the new `<tr>` from the result set.

Something like `$("#ServicesData tr").remove()` if I remember correctly.

Your table header should use `<th>`to avoid removing it.